# Solve $\cos (2x+3y)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\cos (3x+2y)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

We have to solve for $x$ and $y$:

$$\left \{
 \begin{align*}
   \cos (2x+3y) &= \frac{1}{2} \\
   \cos (3x+2y) &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
  \end{align*}
\right.$$

I got
$$\left \{
 \begin{align*}
   2x+3y &= 2n\pi  \pm\frac{\pi}{3} \\
   3x+2y &= 2m\pi \pm\frac{\pi}{6}
  \end{align*}
\right.$$

The final answer in the book is 
$x=\dfrac{1}{5}
\left[ (6m-4n)\pi \pm \dfrac{\pi}{2} \mp \dfrac{2\pi}{3} \right]$

Why is it $\mp \dfrac{2\pi}{3}$?

If for some value we had taken

$$2x+3y=2n\pi -\frac{\pi}{3}$$

and

$$3x+2y=2m\pi +\frac{\pi}{6}$$

The value of $x$ would be

$$\frac{1}{5}[(6m-4n)\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{2\pi}{3}]$$

which is not included in the general solution.

Comment: is this an equation system?

Comment: **In this case**, the notation $\pm a\mp b$ refers to the set $$\{a+b,a-b,-a+b,-a-b\}$$ hence it is equivalent to the notation $\pm a\pm b$ interpreted in the same way (two signs hence four possibilities). Do not ask me to justify its usage, which I think is faulty because of its ambiguities. Sometimes, $\pm a\mp b$ refers to the set $$\{a-b,-a+b\}$$ and this (the sign chosen once and for all hence two possibilities instead of four) is probably what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

$1)$ You have:

$$2x+3y = 2n\pi  \pm\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Multiply by $-2$ and get:

$$-4x-6y = -4n\pi  \mp\frac{2\pi}{3} \quad (I)$$

$2)$ You have:
$$ 3x+2y= 2m\pi \pm\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Multiply by $3$ and get:
$$9x+6y= 6m\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{2}\quad (II)$$

$(I)+(II)$:

$$5x=(6m-4n)\pi \mp\frac{2\pi}{3}\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$$

*PS:* $\mp\frac{2\pi}{3}$ *means that you got opposite signals when multiplied by a negative number, in that case it was* $-2$.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of $y$,
the first equation
is multiplied by 2
and the second by 3
giving
$\pm 2\pi/3\pm\pi/2$.

To get rid of $x$,the first equation is multiplied by 3 
and the second by 2
giving
$\pm \pi\pm\pi/3$.